# How to suggest ideas to the Tor project

Tags: censorship, protocol

I would like to submit one idea to the Tor project, that I found interesting and not implemented yet.

Where can I submit this idea ?

Comment: Something like this ; https://protonmail.uservoice.com/forums/284483-feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending from what exactly you want to propose there are different possibilities:

1. Write to [tor-dev](https://lists.torproject.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/tor-dev)
   This mailing list is the central place where new ideas are discussed. You can meet developers and users there who can give you valuable input.
2. Discuss at IRC (#tor-dev on OFTC)
3. Add an entry at the [bug tracker](https://trac.torproject.org/). Discussions also happen here.

As a last possibility you can also create a proposal, but this should be send to tor-dev and discussed. So you're back at step 1.